# Has John Kerry explained why he is against a new Iran bill?

Tags: iran, barack-obama, jcpoa

John Kerry [said on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JohnKerry/status/867471377238024192):

> After Rouhani’s reelection, there is much up in the air/room for misinterpretation. This is not the moment for a new Iran bill.
>   9:04 PM - 24 May 2017

**Has he made any statements explaining the path for the new Iran Bill?**